# Display powers of 2 on the axis with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to use gnuplot to plot results from my experiments.

I wrote a C++ program that generates a datafile that looks like this:

```
10   3.5
11   3.5
12   3.5
13   3.6
```

What I am trying to do is to display the values of the first column of this datafile on the x-axis as powers of 2. It would look something like that (It doesn't have to look exactly the same):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BSLr.png

So with the datafile I posted, I want to have 2^10, 2^11, etc on the x axis.
Any idea how to do that?

I can change the format of the datafile if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this is done relatively easy by manipulating the `using` specification:

```
plot datafile using (2**$1):2
```

If you do this, you'll probably also want a

```
set logscale x 2
set format x '2^{%L}'  #<- enhanced text.
```

to make the plot look nicer.

Comment: Thanks, It's better now, it displays the right information. However it is not very pretty, it shows 2^{10} etc. The exponent is not placed in the top right corner as one would expect. Someone knows how to do that?

Comment: @fireboot -- You need to use an enhanced terminal.  e.g. `set term postscript enhanced color` or `set termoption enhanced`.

Comment: Bingo. `set terminal png enhanced` instead of `set terminal png` solved the problem. Thanks a lot!