# How to make the x-lable to process geometric progression datas in gnuplot?

Tags: latex, gnuplot

The x-lable datas are geometric progression, like: 50000000, 5000000, 500000, 50000, 5000, 500, 50, 5. However, the default in gnuplot is arithmetic progression. How to make my graph looks good when taking these datas?

Comment: Also closely related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915483/display-powers-of-2-on-the-axis-with-gnuplot/13917604#13917604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use a log scale:

```
set logscale x
```